Centralizing URLs for Doxygen comments. Is there a way to do it outside of markdown?
I'm looking for a way to NOT inline URLs in my doxygen comments.
Doxygen supports this in markdown:
Random markdown referring to [Kohlhoff-1]

...
[Kohlhoff-1]: http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html "System error support in C++0x Part 1"

In the above example "[Kholhoff-1]" can appear multiple times in the markdown. Each time it will be transformed into a URL with the  corresponding link text "System error support in C++0x Part 1". The URL itself need only appear once (I include it at the bottom of the markdown file).
Is there a way to achieve the same thing outside of markdown?

Which version of doxygen are you using? What is there against the current situation? Is it not convenient to the readers of the text? What would you like to see (mockup) ?
